# How To Implement list view item click event using two different tag with same time in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a one list view.
In this listview i used layout which is display below in that layout i use one inner layout which is default **GONE**, 
but when i click on other list view item that layout is visible i want to invisible last clicked layout. and current clicked item layout only expand like in listview

**linear amazon layout expand on and expand off**

> Image 1

[image]

> Image 2 is wrong currently look

[image]

Image 3  i want ?

[image]

> Layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearamazondata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/darkgray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearamazon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/darkgray"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageviewhas"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texttitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/darkgray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textdescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/darkgray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="description"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textprice"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/darkgray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="price"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearimageamazon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonreview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/review" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonaddproducts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/addproducts" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Short Code Used in Lazy Adapter

```
 holder.linearLayoutamazondata.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v)
           {  
              if (holder.linearimageamazon.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) 
              {      
                    holder.linearLayoutamazondata.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkgray);
                holder.linearimageamazon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              } 
              else 
              {    
                   holder.linearLayoutamazondata.setBackgroundResource(R.color.cblack);
                   holder.linearimageamazon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
              }
         }
        });
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of punctuation?  Or do you speak the same way you write?

Comment: no i dont know about punctuation ?

Comment: Obviously. Your question is impossible to read.  Edit it: split it into readable sentences using periods and question marks, use commas to indicate logical pauses in speech.

Comment: @startandroid see this link https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView